# Volley blocking request

Tags: android, android-volley

My problem is that I made a simple data send to a PHP server by using Volley, but sometimes the message doesn't go.
Not even an error is shown in my logcat, also with full internet access

`onClick()` function

```
public void sendServer(View v){
       Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CapitalService.class);           

  mServiceIntent.putExtra("subject", "Photos"); 
                       mServiceIntent.putExtra("reciever", UserNames);
                       mServiceIntent.putExtra("sender", myAcc);
                       mServiceIntent.putExtra("Allmex",Html.fromHtml(imageName)+"");
                       mServiceIntent.putExtra("unique",myData);
                      startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

capitalservice.java

```
public class CapitalService extends IntentService{
    String country = "",Newmessage = "",subject="",reciever="",sender="",Allmex="";
    String capital = "",unique="";
    String url = "";    
    JSONObject obj;
    Context context = this;
    public CapitalService(){
        super("Empty Constructor");     
    }
    public CapitalService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        subject = intent.getStringExtra("subject");
        reciever = intent.getStringExtra("reciever");
        sender = intent.getStringExtra("sender");
        Allmex = intent.getStringExtra("Allmex");
        unique = intent.getStringExtra("unique");
        obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("sender", sender);
            obj.put("reciever",reciever);
            obj.put("message",Allmex);
            obj.put("subject",subject);
            obj.put("id_no",unique);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        makeJsonObjectRequest();

    }      
    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                "*****", obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            response.getString("success");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //some error gone resend the data
                            Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CapitalService.class);
                               mServiceIntent.putExtra("subject", subject); 
                               mServiceIntent.putExtra("reciever", reciever);   
                               mServiceIntent.putExtra("sender", sender);
                               mServiceIntent.putExtra("Allmex",Allmex);
                               mServiceIntent.putExtra("unique",unique);
               mServiceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                              startService(mServiceIntent);
                    }
                });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems no error with the code. have you ever capture the packets to see the network traffic?

Comment: can u also post example JSON request and response.

Comment: @jobcrazy how to capture network traffic

Comment: @AmrutBidri response it post there response.getString("success");  and json request it right

Comment: @Chandani Siddque you will need a rooted phone and push a tcpdump arm version binary into the phone and then capture the traffic with tcpdump